# Help identify this panel AC A-meter

Tags: identification

Could maybe somebody help me identify the following AC panel A-meter?

The outer dimensions are 57mm x 45mm. The panel cut-out is 54mm x 23mm. (Only the upper half of the display protrudes through the panel. The lower half with the adjustment screw remains behind the panel.) It was installed ca. 1998 by a shipyard in Britain.

Alternatively can somebody suggest a replacement that will fit into the existing panel cut-out? All current devices seem to require a significantly larger cut-out in the panel.

[image: Front view]

[image: Side view]

Note: There is perspective-distortion in the following image: The cylinder at the rear of the device does not have a larger diameter than the front of the device is high. The cylinder has a diameter of approximately 37mm.

[image: Rear view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Crompton](https://cromptoncanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/363.pdf). They can probably supply exactly what you need, Challenger series. If you want to search further, that's a "50A bezel-mount analog panel meter". Looks like it has an internal shunt, but many in that current range will be some mV full scale and connect to an external shunt.

[image]

It likely won't be particularly cheap.

Comment: @ARF A third option (in addition to the two in the answer above) for AC measurement is to use a current transformer (mounted remotely around the conductor being measured) connected to a meter with a 1 A or 5 A movement. The dial is printed to show the current being measured. Wiring for this is shown in the link above. You'll need to work out how your existing meter is wired up in order to specify a correct replacement.

Comment: P.S. your title says 'AC' but ensure that is actually correct, esp. given that the case has a '+' molded into it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you very much for your help. It is most definitely an AC A-meter since it is driven by a current transformer placed on a 230V AC line. It has an internal rectifier bridge and load diodes. But thanks for the heads up. :-) I wrote to Crompton to inquire about a suitable replacement.

Comment: @ARF Great. Usually the scale has some markings to show the CT 5A (typically) secondary current, as well as some indication of accuracy, but I guess they went for the 'clean' look.